# Select from one table, and count from another table in same query

Tags: php, mysql

I have quite a bit of knowledge about SQL queries.

I'm trying to make gallery, and I need to select categories from table "cat_photos", which contain rows (id,name,cover,photo) and count number of photos from table "photos" which contain rows (id,thumb,photo,category).

Here is code which i use:

1) Selecting categories

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cat_photos ORDER BY ID DESC");
               while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {       
        echo "<li><a href='photos.php?cat=$data[id]'><img src='galleries/categories/$row[image]' alt='$row[name]' /></a>
              <div class='photodesc'><div class='catname'><a href='photos.php?cat=$row[id]'>$row[name]</a></div>
              <div class='catcount'>Number of photos in category</div></div></li>"; }
```

2) Counting number of photos in category

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT category, COUNT(photo) FROM photos GROUP BY category") or die(mysql_error());
               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "Number of photos is ". $row['COUNT(photo)'] ." in cateogry ". $row['category'] .".";
        echo "<br />"; }
```

Separated all works, but I can't find a way to merge them into one query.
I have googleing for "UNION", "JOIN", "LEFT JOIN" options in MySql query but I could't together the pieces.

I wonder if this is in general possible? 
How in order that query look like?

Comment: forget about the '*' it will eat your performance. (munch, munch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it should work :

```
SELECT cat_photos.*, count(photos.id) as number_photos
FROM cat_photos
LEFT JOIN photos ON photos.category = cat_photos.id
GROUP BY cat_photos.id, cat_photos.name, cat_photos.image
ORDER BY cat_photos.id
```

The number of photos will be accessible trough `$row['number_photos']`.

Comment: There was a little confusion about the table names etc, when I corrected the names of all was opened perfectly. Also remaking this I learned how it works. Thanks a lot. 
Here is remaked code if someone have similar problem: 
`$query = mysql_query("SELECT cat_photos.*, count(photos.id) as number_photos FROM cat_photos LEFT JOIN photos ON photos.category = cat_photos.id GROUP BY cat_photos.id, cat_photos.name, cat_photos.image ORDER BY cat_photos.id") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Yeah right, I copied the wrong table name, I corrected the answer :) glad I could help !

Answer (score 2):

Just use your second query and join the wanted category elements.

Something quick and dirty would be:

```
SELECT c.category, COALESCE(COUNT(p.photo),0) as photos FROM photos p, cat_photos c
WHERE c.category = p.category
GROUP BY category
```

Since I don't know your exact database setup just change the selected elements to the ones you really need.

//edit: Put in Coalesce to get categories with 0 photos.

Comment: Thanks, I hope adding COALESCE fixed that.

Comment: It`s work, but it was easier for me to find out in the Krtek code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't `SELECT *`. Instead select individual columns and then join:

```
SELECT 
  cat_photos_main.id, cat_photos_main.category, cat_photos_main.photodesc, cat_photos_counts.num_photos
FROM cat_photos cat_photos_main
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT category, count(*) AS num_photos FROM photos GROUP BY category) cat_photos_counts 
  ON cat_photos_main.category = cat_photos_counts.category
```

Comment: Your counting the categories, not the photos in each category.

Comment: @Krtek thanks, corrected. Edited so the inner query calls `photos` rather than `cat_photos`

Comment: It`s work, but it was easier for me to find out in the Krtek code.